# Prove that $f(AB)-f(BA) = k(AB - BA)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

if $A$ and $B$ are $3 \times 3$ matrices and , $AB$ has eigenvalues $1,2,2$ (geometric multiplicity of $2$ is $2$) and $f(x$) is a arbitrary function of $x$ then prove $f(AB) - f(BA) = k(AB-BA)$

I really appreciate your helps and advices thanks

Comment: How is $k(AB-BA)$ defined? What is $F(AB)$? Do you mean $f(AB)$?

Comment: It would be better to make some clarifications for the question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde believe it or not its the question :((( AB=A.B and BA=B.A

Comment: I would like to believe you - but you did not yet tell us, what $k$ is! The question is unclear.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco k could be a scaler if F(x) is a linear function of x

Comment: If it's true for polynomial $f$ then the scalar $k$ must be $f(2)-f(1)$.

Comment: It is certainly false without the given condition on the geometric multiplicity of $2$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician why?how could i prove it? u know K is not always a scaler it could be a polynomial of AB and BA.  and also the question itself is the proof of MEAN VALUE THEOREM in 3*3 matrices space with the condition on geometric multiplicity

Comment: OK, I thought that you intended $k$ to be a scalar. Obviously you know a lot more about the question than you are telling us. If we are talking MVT then are these real matrices? What do you mean by "an arbitrary function of $x$" ? (Tell us the domain and range and how it operates on matrices.) Clarify whether $k(AB-BA)$ means some function of $AB-BA$ or a scalar multiple of $AB-BA$.

Comment: I just rewrite the problem without any censored part, k could be scaler if f is a linear function of x, but when f is not linear, like when f(x)=x^2 then k could not be scaler. obviously u know k is f’(c) from MEAN VALUE THEOREM. so if f is linear then f’(x) is a scaler but if f(x) is a function of x^2 or more f’(x) is not scaler. i really dont know the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify any calculations we need to choose sensible bases, so let me start by rephrasing the hypotheses in terms of linear transformations.

Let $V$ be a $3$-dimensional vector space over the field of real number $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\alpha,\beta: V\to V$ be linear transformations. Suppose that $\alpha\beta$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues $1,2,2$.

The first thing to note is that since $\alpha\beta$ is non-singular (its eigenvalues are non-zero) so are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Hence $\alpha^{-1}$ exists, and $\beta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}(\alpha\beta)\alpha$ is similar to $\alpha\beta$ and hence is also diagonalisable with eigenvalues $1,2,2$.

Now consider the intersection of the $2$-eigenspaces of $\alpha\beta$ and $\beta\alpha$. Each is dimension $2$ and $V$ is only dimension $3$, so the intersection has dimension $1$ or $2$.

Consider **the first case**, where the dimension of the intersection is just $1$.

Just as in the proof of the $\dim (U + W)$ theorem we find a basis of $V$. First pick $v_2$ to give a basis of the intersection; then pick $v_1$ so that $v_1,v_2$ give a basis of the $2$-eigenspace of $\alpha\beta$; also pick $v_3$ so that $v_2,v_3$ give a basis of the $2$-eigenspace of $\beta\alpha$. Just as in the proof of the $\dim(U+W)$ theorem $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is a basis of $V$.

Now we can write down the matrices for $\alpha\beta$ and $\beta\alpha$ with respect to this basis; let's call them $X$ and $Y$.

$$
X=\pmatrix{2 &0 & a\\ 0 &2 & b\\0 & 0 & c}, \text{ and }
Y=\pmatrix{d &0 & 0\\ e &2 & 0\\f & 0 & 2}.
$$

Now use the fact that in each case the third eigenvalue is $1$ to get $c=d=1$.

We can now calculate $n$-th powers of $X$ and $Y$ to get

$$
X^n=\pmatrix{2^n & 0 & (2^n -1)a\\0 &2^n & (2^n -1)b\\0 & 0 & 1},
Y^n=\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\(2^n -1)e &2^n & 0\\(2^n -1) f & 0 & 2^n}.
$$

From this we see at once that
$$
X^n - Y^n = (2^n-1^n) (X-Y).
$$

Now turn to **the second case**, where the $2$-eigenspaces coincide. In this case we can pick as basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ of eigenvectors of $\alpha\beta$, where $v_1,v_2$ are also $2$-eigenvectors of $\beta\alpha$. In this case the calculations are even easier, and we obtain the same result.

To conclude, let $f$ be any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[t]$. We then have, by linearity, that 
$$ f(X)-f(Y) = (f(2)-f(1)) (X-Y)$$.

A final remark. I don't think that the field really matters, provided the two eigenvalues are distinct and non-zero. Nor does it matter what the eigenvalues are, provided they differ by $1$.

Comment: thank you very much. the answer is completely making sense to me.